# A graph with a degree sequence 0,1,2,3,4

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Please help me to prove whether or not a there exists a graph with the degree sequence 0,1,2,3,4. I do not know the formal way of writing the proof hence any advises and proofs will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to draw this graph. Start from degree 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** There are 5 vertices. If one has degree $4$, it is connected with all four other vertices. Then which one can have degree 0?

Of course, the above argument only holds if the graph is simple, if you allow multiedges/loops, the answer is different.

Comment: Can you also me with 0,1,2,2,2,3 ?

Comment: @RajindaWickrama The sum of degrees is $10$. Thus there are 5 edges, and 6 vertices. As vertex is isolated, the remaining graph has one more edge than a tree. Thus, you need a cycle with extra  edges. Draw a triangle, and connect it to two other vertices, or a square and connect it to another vertex... And don't forget to add an isolated vertex.